# Unity Registration by Convention with Interface Interception

Tags: c#, unity-container, unity-interception

I am currently trying to use the registration by convention with interface interception. Unfortunately, it seems that I am doing something wrong because I am running in a `StackOverflowException` in the `Unity.Container.dll` on the first resolve...

This is what I tried:

```
container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromAssemblies(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IFoo)), 
  WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface, 
  getInjectionMembers: c => new InjectionMember[] { new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), new InterceptionBehavior<IBarBehavior>()});
```

It seems that now all classes are registered, instead of only classes with matching interfaces (`Foo --> IFoo`). Without the interface interception, the statement is fine and my classes are registered as expected.

Any idea or help would be great!

Update:

I have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24588704/3809520) in a different question that states when a `LifeTimeManager` or `interception` behavior is used all types are registered. By using these information, the following code produced the expected outcome:

```
container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromAssemblies(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IFoo)).
  Where(t => t.GetTypeInfo().GetInterface("I" + t.Name) != null), 
  WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
  getInjectionMembers: c => new InjectionMember[] { new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), new InterceptionBehavior<IBarBehavior>()});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you are running into a **StackOverflowException** because of a **cyclic dependency** issue in your injections. 
This occurs when you are injecting a number of dependencies, say you have,

```
public YourController(IA a, IB b, IC c){  ... }
public ConcreteA(IB b, IC c) { ... }
public ConcreteB(IA a) { ... }
```

The issue, with a set up like this is that, ***ConcreteA needs ConcreteB (IB) so it injects it. While injecting ConcreteB, Unity finds that ConcreteA (IA) is needed so it injects it also, and this will continue in a loop until that stack is overflowed.***

If you start tracing from your default entry point, you find that one or more of your injections are dependent on one another causing a cyclic loading of dependencies like above.

**Once you eliminate this cyclic dependency, you will be fine.**

Comment: I guess the direction is right, but there is no cyclic dependency without the interface interception. So I think there might be something wrong...